# How to monitor directory/file changes to rebuild index?

Tags: ubuntu, search, locate, updatedb

Just moved to Ubuntu 12.04 from Windows 7.

Under Win 7 I use "Everything" to search files and directories, it can build the index database and update it once any file or directory changes. I'm very used to it so I want know if there is something similar under Ubuntu 12.04.

Now my workaround is `updatedb` and `locate`, but I have to `updatedb` every time I want to search something. Also, the results are the absolute file paths, what if I want to know the details of the files?（Say, what should I do if I want to sort the results by created_time?）

Is there any way that `updatedb` is automatically executed once I added a file on my disk? If not, are there any tools that can function like "Everything"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 choices that I'm familiar with.

- [tracker](https://projects.gnome.org/tracker/)
- [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/)
- [Beagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_%28software%29)

This tutorial titled, [The best Linux desktop search tools](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/best-linux-desktop-search-tools) discusses these and a couple of others.

#### Tracker

Installation is a snap.

```
$ apt-get install tracker tracker-utils
```

After installation it should start indexing your drive automatically. You can peek inside to see what it's up to using `tracker-control`:

```
$ tracker-control 
Found 288 PIDs…
Found process ID 2611 for 'tracker-store'

Store:
17 Aug 2013, 11:57:51:  ✓     Store                 - Idle 

Miners:
17 Aug 2013, 11:57:51:  ✗     Applications          - Not running or is a disabled plugin
17 Aug 2013, 11:57:51:  ✗     File System           - Not running or is a disabled plugin
```

Or you can use `track-stats`:

```
$ tracker-stats | head -10
Statistics:
  mfo:Action = 1
  mlo:LandmarkCategory = 15
  mto:State = 6
  mto:TransferMethod = 2
  mtp:ScanType = 6
  nao:Tag = 1
  nco:AuthorizationStatus = 3
  nco:Contact = 1
  nco:Gender = 3
```

You can reconfigure its preferences like so:

```
$ tracker-preferences
```

[image: tracker prefs]

You can manually start up the miners like so:

```
$ tracker-control -s
Starting miners…
  ✓ Applications
  ✓ File System
```

And then see what its up to:

```
$ tracker-control -F
Store:
17 Aug 2013, 12:13:29:  ✓     Store                 - Idle 

Miners:
17 Aug 2013, 12:13:29:    0%  Applications          - Initializing 
17 Aug 2013, 12:13:29:    0%  File System           - Initializing 
Press Ctrl+C to end follow of Tracker state
17 Aug 2013, 12:13:29:  ✓     Store                 - Idle 
17 Aug 2013, 12:13:39:    1%  Applications          - Crawling recursively directory 'file:///usr/share/applications' 
17 Aug 2013, 12:13:39:    1%  Applications          - Crawling recursively directory 'file:///usr/share/desktop-directories' 
17 Aug 2013, 12:13:39:    1%  Applications          - Crawling recursively directory 'file:///home/tammy/.local/share/applications' 
17 Aug 2013, 12:13:39:    1%  Applications          - Crawling recursively directory 'file:///home/tammy/.local/share/desktop-directories'
```

After content on the disk has been indexed you can search for it using either the GUI or the integrated search into Nautilus (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>). It also provides a command line tool, `tracker-search`:

```
$ tracker-search art
Results:
  file:///home/tammy/Documents/ArtEdCurriculumElemFRS.odt
```

A little more details:

```
$ tracker-search -d art
Results:
cols:3
  file:///home/tammy/Documents/ArtEdCurriculumElemFRS.odt
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
    http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo#PaginatedTextDocument
```

You can also invoke the GUI search tool, `tracker-needle`:

[image: ss of tracker-needle]

#### Recoll

I don't have an active setup of this one currently but there are [screenshots on the website](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pics/index.html) that show it in action. You can also peruse the [online documentation](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/index.html) for more information.

Comment: @AmareKnight - glad it solved your problem. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `updatedb` each time a file is created... you will have serious I/O overhead, since `updatedb` parse all your system looking for new files/directories. That said, Ubuntu can install several tools to index user files, the desision of what to use is up to you:

- Tracker only indexing, you need integration with other tool for providing search results.
- [Strigi, nepomuk, and dolphin combination](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167203/how-to-search-for-files-and-file-contents-with-gui#comment205484_167203).
- [Recoll](http://www.recoll.org/) is based on the very strong Xapian search engine library.
- [Beagle](http://www.recoll.org/) searches the content of documents and associated metadata.
- [Namazu](http://www.namazu.org/) is a command-line indexing and search engine.

Most of them are included in the default Ubuntu repositories and can be installed using the Software Center.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like [beagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_%28software%29)?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.